# math arctan does not work in android project

Tags: java, math

In the following code,

```
float i = Float.parseFloat(a);
float j = Float.parseFloat(b);
double div = (double)j/i;  
float theta = (float) Math.atan(Math.toRadians(div));
```

`theta` gets the wrong value. As far I can see, it always computes `Math.tan` (I tried this also and it gives me the same results). So even if I write `Math.tan` or `Math.atan`, I get the same results.

Can anyone help me?

Specific examples:

```
i,j----> theta I get:

3,4-----> 0.023 while the correct one is arctan(4/3)=53.13 not tan(4/3)=0.023
3,6-----> 0.052 while the correct one is arctan(9/3)=71.56 not tan(9/3)=0.052
```

Comment: Can you provide a specific example (i, j, theta)?

Comment: Very odd. Could you try `Math.atan2(j, i)` and see what you get?

Comment: toRadians(4/3) is about 0.023, and atan(0.023) is again about 0.023. Perhaps you didn't want the toRadians step?

Comment: Are you sure you want atan(toRadians( )) not something more like toDegrees(atan())?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you're converting oddly all over the place. Here's what I *think* you want:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        double div = (double)4/3;  
        float theta = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(div));
        System.out.println(theta); // 53.130104
    }
}
```

Assuming you want 4/3 as the gradient, that isn't an *angle* at all - so calling `Math.toRadians` on it is inappropriate. You want to call `Math.atan` on the gradient to get the value in radians, and then `Math.toDegrees` on the radians value to get degrees.